# Differentiation Operator is not a bounded operator for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

If you consider the space of all polynomials on [0,1] (defined as $P_{[0,1]}$ as subspace of $C_{[0,1]}$) then the differentiation operator is not a linear bounded operator on this space. Why is that? this doesn'
t make any sense to me.

Comment: Why would you *expect* it to be bounded? A function can be very steep although it has small values.

Comment: every polynomial is continuously diffble on $[0,1]$ and so the derivative is necessarily bounded on [0,1].

Comment: What is the norm on $P_{[0, 1]}$? Is it the max-norm, the $L^2$ norm, ...?

Comment: sup norm yeah, i was told this is the standard norm for function spaces like C[R]

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to assume that the operator is bounded here. The norm on $C_{[0, 1]}$ measures the size of a function in terms of its values, but the derivative is really about steepness. A function can be arbitrarily steep even though it takes only small values.

To be explicit, the norm of $x^n$ is clearly $1$, while the norm of its derivative is $n$. Draw the picture to see how $x^n$ gets progressively steeper while not getting bigger in value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically [0,1] is a compact interval, and polynomials are continuously differentiable on it (and are thus bounded on [0,1]). This why I cant see a polynomial with unbounded slope. Also $x^n$ has bounded derivative on [0,1] for any fixed $n$? So, that's not a counterexample. I think I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Look at the definition of a bounded linear operator here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator. All you need to do is read the part until the first formula comes up. In order for the operator $L$ to bounded, there must be a constant $M$, that is **independend of the polynomial**, such that $\lVert Lv\rVert \le M \lVert v \rVert$. The example of $v=x^n$ has $\lVert v \rVert = 1, \lVert Lv\rVert = n$. Both of those values are finite, of course, but they show that there **cannot** be a general constant $M$ that fulfills the condition as stated above,